# reconocimiento de texto mediante foto

Tags: android

Mi intención es hacer una app que al hacer una foto a una tarjeta reconozca los datos de la misma y los pueda rescatar.

He leído algo acerca de OCR, pero no tengo ni idea de que trata ni como implementarlo, ademas de si existe versión gratuita.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia y no se ajusta bien al formato del sitio (las respuestas serían largas y muchas de ellas basadas en opiniones), por lo que corre el riesgo de ser cerrada. Intenta encontrar una librería/plugin que te ayude a empezar y entonces será más fácil aclarar las dificultades específicas que tengas.

Comment: Una vez dicho eso, podrías explorar algo como [Bluemix](http://www.ibm.com/Bluemix) o [Haven On Demand](https://www.havenondemand.com/), que incluyen servicios y APIs para OCR que es lo que buscas.([al menos HOD tiene una que puedes ver aquí](https://dev.havenondemand.com/apis/ocrdocument#overview))

Comment: prueba con esta libreria https://www.card.io/

Comment: de acuerdo, me pongo con la de card.io y a ver si se puede hacer algo... gracias a todos! podeis cerrarla y si os apetece ayudarme en el nuevo tema.